# In html5mode urls in angular, if i manually type hashbang(#!) in the url, then it goes in an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hashbang, html5mode

when i type #! manually in my html5mode url, it goes to an infinite digest cycle loop. I want it to redirect to html5mode url, but instead it goes in a redirect loop and the url becomes something like :: - http://localhost:8000/profile/Hotel-Avasa-25196/#!%23%2F!%2F%23%2F!%2F%23%2F!%2F%23%2F!%2F%23%2F3 .....

i have put base href as ::-

```
<base href="/profile/Colors-For-Life-18780/" />
```

and in JS, i have written ::-

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Please Help

Comment: Why would you do that in HTML5 mode? Doesn't HTML5 mode actually turn of the hashbang? If so, whats the point of someone typing it in the browser?

Comment: @Abdel because earlier we used to have hashbang urls. and our earlier mails had urls with hashbang in them, so if some user tries to access the url through that mail , then he will pull off his hair.

Comment: did you try `ui-sref`

Comment: Where are you hosting this? Maybe you can do something like a server redirect to the correct URL if the hashbang one is used.